# Java ChatServer - Optional prefix

Tags: java

I am writing a basic chat server in java, however I have a couple of problems. When someone creates a client or server I would like them to be able to enter a command line argument which is used as a prefix for any message they send. This argument should be optional as well. I have got it working to an extent, for some reason when I send a message it sends the prefix twice, also it is not optional. Any help appreciated, Cheers!

```
public class ReadWriteThread extends Thread {

    private BufferedReader input;
    private PrintWriter output;
    private String prefix;

    public ReadWriteThread(InputStream input, OutputStream output, String prefix) {
        this.input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
        this.output = new PrintWriter(output, true);
        this.prefix = prefix;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            String line;
            while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                output.println(prefix + " " + line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Server {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            int port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
            System.out.println("HELLO " + args[1]);
            String prefix = args[1];
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
            System.err.println("Waiting for a client to connnect");
            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
            System.err.println("Accepted connection on port " + port);
            new ReadWriteThread(System.in, socket.getOutputStream(), prefix).start();
            new ReadWriteThread(socket.getInputStream(), System.out, prefix).start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.err.println("\nUsage: java Server <port>");
        }

    }

}
```

---

```
public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Socket socket = null;
        try {
            int port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
            String prefix = args[2];
            socket = new Socket(args[1], port);
            System.err.println("Connected to " + args[1] + " on port " + port);
            new ReadWriteThread(System.in, socket.getOutputStream(), prefix).start();
            new ReadWriteThread(socket.getInputStream(), System.out, prefix).start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.err.println("\nUsage: java Client <port>");
        }
    }
}
```

Start a server by entering

```
java Server 7777 OPTIONALPREFIX
```

Start a client by entering

```
java Client 7777 localhost
```

Current output on server

```
Waiting for a client to connnect
Accepted connection on port 7777
-->-->hello
-->-->whats up
```

Answer (score 1):

Both client and server prepend a prefix to their message and you've probably set `-->` as the prefix for both of them.

So the client might send

```
--> hello
```

then the server receives it and prepends his own prefix before logging it to the console

```
--> --> hello
```

Why is prefix not optional? Because you're always trying to read it, you never check the number of arguments passed to the program beforehand.

```
String prefix = args[1];
```

In order to access `args[1]` you first need to check whether `args` contains two arguments.

Comment: On client side, the line "new ReadWriteThread(System.in, socket.getOutputStream(), prefix).start();" will send text + prefix to the server. On server side,  the line "new ReadWriteThread(socket.getInputStream(), System.out, prefix).start();" will display the text receive from the client (and so, with the prefix) and will add the prefix => so here, you have twice the preifx